# mscvp80d.dll is missing. How to link against a more recent version? (MS Visualstudio 2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, vcredist

im trying to compile a solution in MS VS 2012 which was original written in MS VS 2005 (? I'm not sure but it is a much older version).

The compiling and linken works without any problems. But when I try to start the exe I'll get an error which says:

"msvcp80d.dll is missing from your computer"

I tried to install the old vc++ redist package, but this ships only with non debug version of the library.

Anyone knows how to force VS to link against a newer version of msvcp80d.dll. (should be msvcp110d.dll in this case). I already updated the complete solution without success. The plattformtoolset is set to "Visual Studio 2012 (v110)" but this seems to be ignored.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must rebuild the DLL or library that still has the dependency on msvcp80d.dll.

Comment: ok thanks for the hint. i didn't check this. Indeed I forgot to recompile one lib! Thank you!!